# How to put functions in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I was wondering why it seems not possible to put functions into a list
using a for loop like below:

```
    K = Table[{}, {2}];
    For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++,
      S = SmoothKernelDistribution[RandomReal[1, 10]];
      Print[PDF[S, 0.5]];
      K[[i]] = Function[x, PDF[S, x]];
    ]
```

Although `S` changes, the list `K` does contain twice the same function.
(It was simplified for 2, usually I have thousands of functions in the loop and S is much more complex.)

Comment: 1. use `Table` insead of `For` e.g. `k = Table[...`. 2. don't use single capital letters. 3. you need to use `With[{s =s},..` trick because `Function` is `HoldAll`. Read more in linked duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! k = Table[
  s = SmoothKernelDistribution[RandomReal[1, 10]];
  With[{s = s}, PDF[s, #] &], {i, 1, 2}] works as intended.